# Как генерировать страницу по шаблону в react js

Tags: html, reactjs

Здравстуйте, как сделать что бы по нажатию кнопки edit(с картинки 1) генерировалась страница по шаблону с данными из БД (как на картинке 2)

Каким образом это можно реализовать на реакте? Или дайте плиз наводку где про это можно посмотреть

(На картинках изображён набросок того как должна выглядеть страница и где какой элемент будет располагаться)

[image: картинка 1]

[image: картинка 2]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам потребуется применить шаблонизатор. Это такой компонент на React, который генерирует форму из объекта с данными и json шаблона. Содержимое excel документа потребуется привести к виду, который сможет прочитать шаблонизатрр

> Сам json можно получить из файла xlsx [используя функцию parseExcel из gist](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/2fd63d39be0f1d21711c1ec1a2b5108d). Работает как в NodeJS, так и браузере

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import { One, FieldType } from "react-declarative";

const fields = [
  {
    type: FieldType.Text,
    title: "First name",
    name: "firstName"
  },
  {
    type: FieldType.Text,
    title: "Age",
    inputFormatterTemplate: "000",
    inputFormatterAllowed: /^[0-9]/,
    name: "age"
  }
];

const initialData = {
  firstName: 'Petr',
  age: '23',
};

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const handleChange = (data) => setData(data);

  return (
    <>
      <One handler={data} fields={fields} onChange={handleChange} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону [jsonforms](https://jsonforms.io/) или [react-declarative](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-declarative).

[image: screenshot]

Ссылка на [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-declarative-one-yjbjto?file=/src/App.js), чтобы потыкать в браузере

Comment: Укажите `javascript` после трех апострофов, чтобы код правильно подсветило)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, хороший совет, спасибо!